# Reading multiple children from firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an attendance app with android studio. Part of this includes a history button that lists the student's personal attendance history. However, I'm having trouble reading data while specifying a path. I've googled various solutions, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

```
package com.example.android.teamnahhseproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

public class attendance_history_student extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("teamnahh-7d81b/student_users/Alisha Tapiawala/classes/CS 3354_003");
String attendance_text;
TextView textBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance_history_student);

    textBox = findViewById(R.id.attendance);

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                attendance_text = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                textBox.append(attendance_text + "\n");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
}
```

}

[image: realtime database data]

I'm trying to print out all the children for "CS 3354_003"

Comment: Did my answer using a `ValueEventListener` help?

Comment: I tested with this code Log : ***Log.w(postSnapshot.getKey(), postSnapshot.getValue(String.class));*** and its working. What is appearing for you in the TextView?

Comment: well.... when tested on my apartment wifi rather than my school wifi it seems to work lol. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
ArrayList<String> presence = new ArrayList<String>();
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student_users/Alisha Tapiwala/classes/CS3354_003");
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
         for( DataSnapshot children : dataSnapshot.getChildren(){
             presence.add(children.child(" ").getValue(String.class));
             //presence is now containing the values from the database. 
         }
    }
};
dbref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Sorry if the formatting is not right, especially the {}. I did this on my phone. If you are still receiving errors check out [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("teamnahh-7d81b/student_users/Alisha Tapiawala/classes/CS 3354_003");
```

to

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("student_users/Alisha Tapiawala/classes/CS 3354_003");
```

The `teamnahh-7d81b` is not needed in your reference.